# How to activate a validator in a local testnet?

Tags: go-ethereum, testnets, validators, beacon-chain, lighthouse

I am trying to add a validator to my local testnet, however the validator keeps giving the same message ( awaiting activation );

[image: validator output]

For context, the **network topology** is as follows;

There are two computers, Computer A and Computer B. i use geth (execution client) + lighthouse (consensus client)

i started the local testnet on computer A. i successfully peered the testnet on computer A with a setup of geth+lighthouse on computer B. But, when i try to add the validator on **computer B**, it just says " awaiting activation " - which makes me think that i need to make a deposit for the new validator on computer B.

The screenshot above is for the validator i am trying to add on Computer B

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!